# MMDrawerController: pushing viewcontroller form application open URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, mmdrawercontroller

I've got an app that is a list of itens in a table view and displays a detail view controller to every item on the table view. It also implements MMDrawerController (root view controller) as a side menu with storyboard.
I'm deep linking my app and using application open URL source application annotation method from App Delegate to handle it. So, I want to push a detail view controller from this method using MMDrawerController and I'm having some trouble.
Have a look in some code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
      DetalheRestauranteViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detalheRest"];

      MMDrawerController* drawerController = (MMDrawerController *)self.window.rootViewController;
      // If I use this nothing happens        
      [drawerController.centerViewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

      // If I use this nothing happens      
      [((MMDrawerController *)self.window.rootViewController).centerViewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

     // If I use this I got the unrecognized selector error       
     [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

    return YES;
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you please log url, sourceApplication and annotation ?

Comment: What exactly you want me to log?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that with deep linking and the new iOS9 menu shortcuts that a small delay is often needed to display or manipulate UI Components.

I would try moving all of your UI/MMDrawer code to its own method. Then when openURL is called in your app delegate, call your new method on a delay.

So in ObjC it would look something like this:

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(showDetailView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing changed.

Comment: Is it possible that your root view controller is a different class? NSLog [self.window.rootViewController class] and see what you are actually working with.

Comment: The root view controller is MMDrawerController. I just tested it.

Comment: Have you messed around with the delay time? If it is indeed an MMDrawerController then calling your method should work. I'd try something silly like 5 seconds just to see if it will do anything. Set breakpoints to make sure they correct method is getting hit.

Comment: No, I did not. I'm gonna use a diferente strategy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do you solve this problem?

I tried many times. Finally I found it works fine for me today:

```
[((UINavigationController *)((MMDrawerController *)self.window.rootViewController).centerViewController)  pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
MMDrawerController *mvc = (MMDrawerController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *nvc = (UINavigationController *)mvc.centerViewController;
[nvc pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

These two kinds of writing are the same.

Here vc is one DetalheRestauranteViewController instance.